# Create custom AudioVideo Call Lync 2010

Tags: wpf, lync

I'm new at using Lync SDK. And i want to create an custom application i WPF where i have defined an screen where the video is placed, and just two buttons used to connect and disconnect. I have searched Google thin and the only thing i have found is the Microsoft Lync Client.

Comment: Can you give some more info - will the lync client be installed on the machine the app is on? what are you connecting to? an existing conference, or starting a new video call with an existing user? Is this a Kiosk-type application?

Comment: Offcourse. Right now im using Microsoft Office365 with an Lync Server on. Right now i can on push an call button and the Lync Client pops in front. But i dont want that. I want to define in my app where the video screen is located and a button to start a call and end it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [docking the conversation window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378625.aspx). This would leave Lync running and usable on the machine, but would bring the entire conversation window into your app.

Alternatively, you could use [UI Suppression mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh345230.aspx) - This is appropriate for Kiosk-type apps, it means the Lync client isn't runnable, but you then have full control over starting conversations and displaying the UI to host those conversations. It does mean you have to create all the UI you need - you can't use Lync controls etc. You can get hold of the video window handle and use it to dock into a WPF WindowsFormsHost control.

Comment: Hey. I have the tryed what you said. But i havent got i to work. What i liked was something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228134.aspx just without IM and insted using Video.

Comment: I think the example you linked to works by using Lync in automation mode, then docking the conversation window into a custom (hidden) panel, and then reimplementing the text controls etc. This approach won't work for video, as the video window is only available programatically when Lync is running in UI suppression mode

Comment: True. It looks like the only way is to use an Kiosk like app.

Comment: I wonder if this (unsupported hack) might help - sending a message to the Lync conversation window via Win32 to pop out the Video window - you could then dock the main conversation window to hide it, and dock the video window using Win32 SetParent - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/da8c509e-8f5c-4848-85ed-86fa83d05982